# Failed azure shared disk with Premium_LRS

Tags: azure, file, share, smb

I follow this link page for create a disk share with Premium LRS in Azure with failed result, but only is for Premium storage selected because I select a Statard LRS the file share is created ok:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-premium-fileshare

```
Create a storage account
az storage account create -n $AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME -g $AKS_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP -l $AKS_PERS_LOCATION --sku "Premium_LRS"
Export the connection string as an environment variable, this is used when creating the Azure file share
#$AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = az storage account show-connection-string -n $AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME -g $AKS_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP -o tsv

Get storage account key
$STORAGE_KEY=$(az storage account keys list --resource-group $AKS_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --account-name $AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --query "[0].value" -o tsv)
Create the file share
#az storage share create -n $AKS_PERS_SHARE_NAME --connection-string $AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
az storage share create --account-name $AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --account-key $STORAGE_KEY --name $AKS_PERS_SHARE_NAME

This latest shared create command is always failed with message:

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='$AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.file.core.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /$AKS_PERS_SHARE_NAME?restype=share (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x05A199F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

As well I investigate creation storage account via Azure portal, selecting Premium LRS, but once is created, it not include nothing to file share support (only Blob), so Why there is a official link page about it? Is a feature deprecated but not remove of documentation ? I opened a case on that page documentation but that was closed indicating I have open in this community first.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the link. What's wrong is that you miss the parameter `--kind FileStorage` when you create the storage account. So what you need to do is that recreates the storage account again adding the parameter behind:

```
az storage account create -n $AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME -g $AKS_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP -l $AKS_PERS_LOCATION --sku "Premium_LRS" --kind FileStorage
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing!! I have created succesfull , only a note, **the correct param is : --kind** , not -Kind (I will report this problem to the documetnation page):

`az storage account create -n $AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME -g $AKS_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP -l $AKS_PERS_LOCATION --sku "Premium_LRS"  -Kind "FileStorage" 
az: error: unrecognized arguments: -Kind FileStorage`

**Successful command with --kind**:

`az storage share create --account-name $AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --account-key $STORAGE_KEY --name $AKS_PERS_SHARE_NAME
{
  "created": true
}
`

Comment: @jmorcar Well, if it works for you please accept it as the answer. :-)

Comment: @jmorcar What is the reason that you do not mark my answer when it solves your problem?!